# How to dismiss the PopupWindow on touching outside area of it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-popupwindow

I have searched on this. However not a single solution worked.

PopupWindow is set, the only thing I would love to happen is when I click outside the popup it should get dismiss or cancel.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: Its for `Dialog` or `ProgressDialog` not for `PopupWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this  function with pop up `setOutsideTouchable` call's parameter to true:

```
pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

hopefully it will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.something));
```

Comment: You should elaborate - tell why this is an answer. Hit edit and expand the answer with your thoughts.